# post request from json to java spring + javascript

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I need to pass json using a post request.
javascript code:

```
import axios from "axios";



export default class UserService {

    static async post(){
        const response = await axios.post('https://26.234.184.107:8080/products/post', {name: 22})
        console.log(response.data)
        // return response
    }
}
```

and I accept java like this:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class PostController {

    static HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    static {
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-total-count, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date");
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH");
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-total-count, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date");
        responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        responseHeaders.set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }


    @PostMapping("/products/post")
    public ResponseEntity<String> post(@RequestBody Human human) {
        System.out.println(human.getAge());
        return new ResponseEntity<>("sd", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        //return new ResponseEntity<>(String.valueOf(new JSONObject(URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8")).getInt("name")), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I tried to make a request to the server via postman and everything works for me there.
I tried to copy the code from the postman generator to javascript and nothing happened, it still doesn't work

Comment: Instead of `https://26.234.184.107:8080/products/post` it should be `'https://26.234.184.107:8080/products/post'`

Comment: It's there, I copied it crookedly

Comment: Are there any errors in the dev tools? What is the status of this request in the network tab?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://26.234.184.107:8080/products/post' from origin 'http://localhost:3000/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.